# Is it unsafe to add localhost to Content Security Policy?

Tags: html, localhost, xss, content-security-policy

I have the following `meta` tag set in my `index.html` which simplifies local development but will also be deployed in the production code:

```html
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' localhost:* ws://localhost:*;">
```

Are there any known ways that adding `localhost` like this could allow any type of cross-site scripting exploits?

According to [Google's CSP evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com) it seems okay (well, the `localhost` portion at least).

Comment: Why invest time into that? Just don't deploy development settings to a production environment. You should really be able to keep those two environment apart...

Comment: The time investment to keep it the way it is now is zero. There is currently no extra processing step required when deploying the static html files.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This isn't optimal, but it will not meaningfully reduce the security of your users.

The reason for this is that browser and computer form the trusted computing base for any web page. If you're browsing from an untrusted machine, there's no security rules in the world a web page can implement to guarantee the safety of your data and privacy of the exchange.

Comment: Given that [it is possible to spoof localhost](https://serverfault.com/a/752076), wouldn't it theoretically be possible for someone to serve something from http://localhost without actually compromising a user's computer?

Comment: The answer you linked regards incoming packet spoofing. With CSP we are setting constraints for a client, not a server. Additionally, a website served with these headers instructs the browser to allow connections to localhost, if the browser receives that rule and allows a connection to anything else because of bugs, spoofing, etc. it is a flaw in the browser or operating system, not our CSP rule.